# Sacar valores de un spinner que tiene un adaptador

Tags: java, android-studio, android-spinner, arrayadapter

Tengo un spinner que lo adapto de un cardview y los datos vienen de una api, lo que pasa es que siempre me identifica que tiene seleccionado el primer valor de mi lista, y muevo el spinner pero no me identifica cual elijo despues. Este es mi código despues de obtener los datos de la api

Si me muestra el contenido de la api, sin problema alguno.

```
   if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    tarjetaL = response.body();
                    custtar = new CustomTarjetas(response.body(), Principal.this);
                    spinner.setAdapter(custtar);
                    int position = 0;
                    String o = tarjetaL.get(position).getAbreviacion();
             
                    Toast.makeText(Principal.this, String.valueOf(o), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Agrego una parte de CustomTarjetas

```
   public List<Moneda> tarjetaL;
    public Context context;

    public CustomTarjetas(List<Moneda> tarjetaL, Context context) {
        this.tarjetaL = tarjetaL;
        this.context = context;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.linear_pais, null);
        ImageView imagen = view.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
        TextView moneda = view.findViewById(R.id.moneda);
        TextView abreviacion = view.findViewById(R.id.abreviacion);

        String mon;
        mon = tarjetaL.get(position).getMoneda();
        moneda.setText(mon);

        String abr;
        abr = tarjetaL.get(position).getAbreviacion();
        abreviacion.setText(abr);

        String img;
        img = tarjetaL.get(position).getImagen();

        switch (img){
            case "euro.png":
                imagen.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.francia));
                break;
            case "dolar.png":
                imagen.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.dolar));
                break;
            case "pesosmx.png":
                imagen.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.mexico));
                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error al obtener imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: agrega el código de tu adapter CustomTarjetas

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener el texto seleccionado de tu `spinner` usando [OnItemSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) mediante la posición del elemento:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Seleccionaste: " +
                    adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
               //No selecciono nada.
        }
    });
```